# resharper expression body format

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm attempting to get Resharper to format expression body getter and setters like this.

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get => _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    private set => _userManager = value;
}
```

However, when I run code clean up it reformats the property to

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager { get => _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); private set => _userManager = value; }
```

Which I find less readable because it pushes my code off the screen

**Question**

What setting or combination thereof do I need to adjust in ReSharper such that ReShaper will reformat my code to look like the first example?

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Maybe enabling `Autoformat on semicolon`(I know is a Jetbrains image, but should be the same on VS)  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/37228482/AutoFormatOff.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correct Answer:**

`ReSharper` -> `Options` -> `Code Editing` -> `C#` -> `Formatting Style` -> `Line Breaks and Wrapping` -> `Arrangement of Declaration Blocks` -> `Place simple property/indexer/event declaration on single line` = Unchecked

**Original Answer:**

`ReSharper` -> `Options` -> `Code Editing` -> `C#` -> `Formatting Style` -> `Line Breaks and Wrapping` -> `Arrangement of Attributes` -> `Place accessor attribute on same line` = `Never`

Comment: close but that has to do with [Attributes] not expression body getter and setters

Comment: hmm, just added another one to try in the answer. is that what you need?

Comment: Yes that was it